# Can I drag a file out of a node-webkit app and drop it on the Desktop?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, chromium, node-webkit

The client is trying to figure out whether they'd like to go with a node-webkit app with AngularJS, but their one sticking point is that they'd like to be able for their users to drag a file out of the app and onto the desktop or an email client (such as Outlook or Lotusnotes) like you can do with an applet (which I'm desperately trying to avoid).

As far as I can tell, this doesn't look possible, but I'm not well versed yet with the latest stuff you can do with HTML5 and Chrome specifically. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** I've also never used node.js

Comment: I believe that this will not be possible, because what you have with node-webkit is a frameless browser; and you can't drag "files" from a browser...

Comment: After searching around a bit, it seems the closest you can get is to drag the uri from an anchor. I'm still hoping someone knows something we don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/#toc-dnd-files

http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-dragout

The answer is yes. Here is some more text so that I can submit my answer.

Comment: this does not seem to work on linux.
tested it on fedora and lubuntu,
both with the google-chrome-beta package from the respective os repositories.

Answer (score 0):

@tjb1982 Using a demo like this one:
http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-dragout worked for simple files, but when trying to drag a WAV file or MP3 file into a audio software( like logic, pro tools, ableton ) they won't recognise it as an audio file.